# docker on windows 10: container has no ip address

Tags: docker, localhost, containers

First step: I loaded the Images from a local drive:

```
docker load -i postgres10.tar
docker load -i drupaldrush1.tar
```

Second step: I started the containers:

```
 docker run -p5432:5432 postgres:10
 docker run -p8081:8081 drupaldrush:1
```

Third step: displaying containers:

```
docker ps
```

results in:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
b77bcc79d599        drupaldrush:1       "docker-php-entrypoi…"   33 seconds ago       Up 32 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   flamboyant_easley
97b9ba5f2779        postgres:10         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp           competent_fermat
```

BUT container is not available under: localhost:8081

Fourth step: inspecting container:

```
 docker inspect flamboyant_easley
```

resulting in (among other Information):

```
"HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8081/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8081"
                }
            ]
        },
```

and

```
  "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",

        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "d5e552bf9c57050fe2debfc7d38a784580309fa0b72c4854a563e78295128912",
                "EndpointID": "f61b02c5997b2e391add348686f658b4c596dd60495365cee0fee539743d4792",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
```

Problem: The container is not available under localhost:8081 and not under 172.17.0.3: 8081 or 172.17.0.1:8081 
Question: What do I have to do to make it run under localhost:8081?

Comment: Your `docker run` command looks correct.  The `docker ps` output hints that the container's Dockerfile has an EXPOSE 80 line, and the service inside the container might be listening on the normal HTTP port; does `-p8081:80` instead help?  The container-internal IP address usually isn't useful for anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problems came from Docker for Windows. Now I got a Linux Laptop and everything works just fine.